# How to find Marshallian demand of $u(x,y,z)=x+y^2+2z^2$?

Tags: consumer-theory

Consider the utility function $u(x)=x+y^2+2z^2$. How to derive Marshallian demand for a consumer with these preferences?

Comment: Just construct the Lagrangean using the budget constraint $$M = p_{x}x + p_{y}y + p_{z}z$$ and take the first order conditions and solve each. The result will be the Marshallian demand.

Comment: @Brennan Does the **convexity** of this function not matter at all, are you sure first order conditions are sufficient?

Comment: That's why I'm asking, I can't get far with the usual interior conditions.

Comment: @Giskard very good point that I overlooked

Answer (score 3):

Just compare the utilities of these three bundles: $\left(\frac{M}{p_X}, 0, 0\right)$, $\left(0, \frac{M}{p_Y}, 0\right)$ and $\left(0,0, \frac{M}{p_Z}\right)$ and consume the one that yields highest utility.

Comment: Is this because it will be a corner solution?

Comment: It'll be a corner solution because the utility function is strictly quasi convex.